# Join equivalent query

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I have a simple enough query that will be used as part of a SP to clean the database from time to time. TableA and TableB are related with a ID. I build a table variable with all the IDs in TableA and then delete all the one that appear in TableB. This sintax works just fine:

```
DELETE @TableIds
FROM @TableIds AS tids
WHERE tids.sharedID IN (SELECT tb.sharedID FROM TableB AS tb WITH (nolock))
```

How can this query be done with a JOIN instead of a IN (subquery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a table variable to do this. Use `delete` with a `join` so the matched id records can be deleted.

```
delete a
from tablea a
join tableb b on a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
  DELETE Tids
  FROM @TableIds AS tids
  INNER JOIN TABLEb TB(Nolock) ON TIDS.SHAREID=        TB.SHAREId
```